# modify database after time limit

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008

I am implementing a database which takes requests and reply them as `Approved` or `Denied`

i want to add feature so that in case particular request not responded in 3days, it will auto replied as `Denied`. Its a status field in database.

I am using sql server 2008 with linq in asp.net 3.5
Is there any way other than checking on each loading time?

Comment: Sure you could use a SQL Agent Job, Scheduled Task, SSIS package. Can you be a little more specific about your needs?

Comment: to be precise, i am handling leave transactions, if i apply leave for this  months month end then its status should be `pending` till a day before month end. On month end it should be auto changed to `Request Denied`. 
<br> how to get this? I haven't ever used SQL Agent Job, Scheduled Task, SSIS package. But bit aware about the services. 
<br>In this criteria what would be more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: My answer is similar to @AnandPhadke 's but with a small difference.

I have had this problem my self several times.

1) I usually build a "Robot" for these kind of tasks.

By "Robot", I mean a really simple console application which only checks the database and performs the desired actions depending on the database result. This console application is also being able to log its' activity (for debugging purposes and so on, you can for example use open source log4net for this task).

2) Then I let the standard Windows "Task Scheduler" call my console application periodically.

Here are more information about the "Task Scheduler": http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

This is the principal I'm trying to describe
[image: Principal]

There are several things that might affect the load on your CPU. Computation intensive operations at first. I have no idea what you DB design looks like at all but I sure know that the more complex your SQL query is (*and the more data* this complex query has to be processed on) it will need more power from the CPU. Try to optimize your query.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, which will be more resource hungry?
a) adding console app and calling thru task manager or
b) calling a web service?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "resource hungry"? :-) If you let the "Task Scheduler" periodically run your console application - then it consume some of the system resources when executing. If you call the console logic from a web service - then it consume some of the system resources when executing from there. 

I'm absolute not trying to foolish you but I probably misunderstand what you are asking for. According to my opinion, I strongly suggest the "Task Schedule" - console application - solution because of its' simplicity.

Comment: i meant what if consumes more CPU... does size of database matters to your solution?

Comment: I have updated my answer. There are more things than only the size of database that affects your CPU.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is,

Write a windows service whic will check the db after every given time interval and perform the operations.Just keep this Windows service running always.At each time interval it will do the job.

Comment: hi @AnandPhadke thank you fr suggestion, using this scenario, how much load will it be added to the connectivity?

Comment: It will have to connect to db at each interval and if anything in a table to process then continue else just close the connection.And it depends on how frequently you want to connect to db.I mean the time interval. I guess you can give delay of lets say 5min or 10min.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to modify a record in SQL server after an interval, use SQL Server Agent. You can set up a job that runs at any time period you want, and it can run something like a stored procedure which could check for what you want it to and update the records that match. Here is a tutorial on how to set up a job:

http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ss/sql_server_agent_3.htm